# unix shell scripting- Using mv command in if condition

Tags: bash, unix

I want to move a file to a folder based on its file extension. 
example: if the file is .csv,it should move to COMPLETED folder , if the file has any extension other any .csv then it should move to REGULAR folder.

Below is my shell script and its not working. Can you let me know what is the problem with it?

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /apps/int/apd/$1/work

if ls /apps/int/apd/$1/work/*.csv &> /dev/null; then
    mv *.csv /apps/int/apd/$1/COMPLETED
else
    /apps/int/apd/$1/Regular
fi
```

Answer (score 5):

Why do you have to check the existence of `*.csv` files?

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /apps/int/apd/$1/work

mv *.csv /apps/int/apd/$1/COMPLETED 2>/dev/null
mv * /apps/int/apd/$1/Regular
```

Here first `.csv` files are moved to `COMPLETED` folder. Then rest of the files are moved to `Regular` folder.

I am assuming you have created `COMPLETED` and `Regular` folders.

Comment: Checking for csv files before calling `mv` allows you to separate the two possible ways `mv` could fail: not being able to move the file literally named "*.csv", and not being able to move actual csv files.

Comment: But from the requirement, what i see is any file with extension `.csv` should be moved. So, even if the filename is literally "*.csv", i guess that should also be moved.

Comment: Most likely, though, is that there is no file named `*.csv`, but that is the name passed to `mv` by the shell, which will cause `mv` to fail. Since you silence the error message to avoid seeing that, you won't know if there was some other problem with the `mv`, like the directory `COMPLETED` not existing. It's better to test for the error conditions you *can* anticipate and show the messages for the errors you cannot. One possible consequence is that the first `mv` fails, then *all* the files are moved into `Regular`.

Answer (score 0):

Change YOUR_PATH with your specific path and your path for /COMPLETED/ and /REGULAR/.

If I got what you wanted to explain i think your variables look like theese:

```
/YOUR_PATH/ = /apps/int/apd/$1/work
/COMPLETED/ = /apps/int/apd/$1/COMPLETED
/REGULAR/ = /apps/int/apd/$1/Regular
```

You can try this. :)

```
#!/bin/bash

for filename in /YOUR_PATH/*;
do
    Path="$filename"
    extension="${filename##*.}"
    if [ "${extension}" = 'csv' ]; then
            mv $Path /COMPLETED/
    else
            mv $Path /REGULAR/
    fi
done
```

If you need anything pls leave a comment. :)